# Open balls and metric induzed by a norm

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces

Define two norms on $C^1([a,b])$, $\|f\|_0=\max\limits_{x \in [a,b]}|f(x)|$ and  $\|f\|_1=\max\limits_{x \in [a,b]}|f(x)|+\max\limits_{x \in [a,b]}|f'(x)|$. We can define two open balls (centered in $0$) $$B_r^0(0)=\{f \in C^1[a,b];\|f\|_0 <r \}$$ and $$B_r^1(0)=\{f \in C^1[a,b];\|f\|_1 <r \}.$$

There is two things i need to prove: $B_r^1(0)\subset B_r^0(0)$ and that there is no $\epsilon>0$ that satisfies $B_\epsilon^0(0) \subset B_r^1(0)$.

I'm a little bit confused in how i work with this. For the first affirmation, I think that i can visualize it, the derivative is the tangent line and it is in a radius $r$, but I didn't managed to formalize it. There is some hint that i can use?

Thanks!

Comment: I am sure you can answer the first part yourself if you try.

Comment: I'm really stucked at this, i try to get some intuition using easy functions like $f(x)=x$ in $[0,1]$, i get $\|f\|_0=1$ and $\|f_1\|=2$, but i didn't get how this will help.

Comment: @Lucascantu Write $A$ for the max of $|f|$ and $B$ for the max of $|f'|$. Then $||f||_{0} = A$ and $||f||_{1} = A+B$. Are you sure you can't compare them?